# Apache 2.4 how to enable rewrite module

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I try to enable rewrit module on apache serveur 2.4 and Debian 8
I have created a subdomaine

If I create an php file with :

```
<?php
 if(!function_exists('apache_get_modules') ){ phpinfo(); exit; }
 $res = 'Module Unavailable';
 if(in_array('mod_rewrite',apache_get_modules())) 
 $res = 'Module Available';
echo apache_get_version();
?>
```

It display "Module Available"

In the global directive (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf) I have create :

```
<Directory /var/dev/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks                            
 AllowOverride all                                         
 Require all granted                                       
</Directory>
```

I have create a .htaccess file on root web folder

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^foo.html$  test.html
```

And an test.html file !

In appache error log I have this :

[Thu Dec 22 11:36:44.828831 2016] [core:info] [pid 1884] [client 83.145.73.220:58115] AH00128: File does not exist: /home/dev/foo.html

Thank for your help

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. All you need to do in your terminal is

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then just restart apache2

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```